# How do limit cycles explain curvilinear asymptotes?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, intuition

I'm a 17 years old and I have no clue about a concept known as limit cycles. I looked it up and I understand it represents the orbit of functions approaching other  A person told me that limit cycles had something to do with non-linear asymptotes(curved, function-like asymptotes). If you look it up in wikipedia the actual definition is curvilinear asymptotes.

For example if we take a function such as $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^3+5x+5}}{x+5}$$. We can use manipulation by limits to get...

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^3+5x+5}}{x+5}$$
$$\sqrt{\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3+5x+5}{x^2+10x+25}}$$

Then using polynomial division.

$$\sqrt{x-10+\frac{80x+255}{x^2+10x+25}}$$
$$\sqrt{x-10}$$
So...
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^3+5x+5}}{x+5}=\sqrt{x-10}$$

Now how do limit cycles explain this? I appreciate any help from people who is mathematically wise to explain this.

Comment: The limit you are computing is in fact $\infty$.  In general, the value $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x)$, if defined, is a value that does not depend on $x$, since we take the limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Example:  $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{5x^2+2}{6x^2+x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{5 + 2/x^2}{6 + 1/x} =  \frac{5}{6}$.

Comment: Yes the limit approaches infinity, but it is approaching a curve and the curve is approaching $\infty$. If you take $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^3+5x+5}}{x+5}-\sqrt{x-10}$ then it will be zero. If you don't believe me look up curvilinear asymtotes. So basically, as $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^3+5x+5}}{x+5}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x-10}=\infty$. Basically like a "double limit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing a basic limit, which does not really have anything to do with a "limit cycle."

People usually talk about limit cycles in the context of a dynamic system.  An example is the following:  Define a function $f(x)$ by:

$$ f(x) = -\arctan(3x) $$

Consider the following dynamical system:  Take any nonzero value $x_0$ and define:

\begin{align} 
&x_1 = f(x_0)\\
&x_2 = f(x_1)\\
&x_3 = f(x_2)\\
&x_4 = f(x_3)\\
\end{align}

and so on, so that $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$.  Try it.  Here is what I get with $x_0=1$:

\begin{align}
&x_0=1\\
&x_1=-1.249045772398254\\
&x_2=1.310003745871587\\
&x_3=-1.321631768605089\\
&x_4= 1.323735486003704\\
&x_5=-1.324112374293736\\
&x_6=1.324179776191448\\
&x_7=-1.324191826399697\\
&x_8=1.324193980631707 \\
&x_9=-1.324194365742789\\
&x_{10}=1.324194434588798
\end{align}

Here is what I get with $x_0=100$: 
\begin{align} 
&x_0=100\\
&x_1= -1.567463005807160  \\
&x_2=  1.361259896088634  \\
&x_3=  -1.330650571776570 \\
&x_4=  1.325343336954363 \\
&x_5= -1.324399667758768  \\
&x_6= 1.324231130910750  \\
&x_7= -1.324201006895994  \\
&x_8= 1.324195621816688  \\
&x_9=-1.324194659135894 \\
&x_{10} = 1.324194487038431
\end{align}

It can be shown that there is a special point $x^*>0$ such that $f(f(x^*)) = x^*$, and whenever $x_0\neq 0$ the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ approaches the "limit cycle" of alternating between $x^*$ and $-x^*$.  In particular, if $x_0>0$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{2n} = x^*$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{2n+1} = -x^*$. You can say that the dynamics asymptotically approach a "period 2 orbit," even though the sequence never actually repeats itself (unless you use either $x_0=x^*$, $x_0=-x^*$, or $x_0=0$). The case $x_0=0$ yields the "unstable stationary behavior" $x_n=0$ for all $n$ (unstable because if there is any slight deviation in the initial condition, the trajectory will converge to the limit cycle instead of the all-zero behavior).

---

You also get limit cycles in astronomy:  Imagine a comet that shoots near the sun, gets trapped by the sun's gravity, and ends up orbiting the sun in a trajectory that approaches an ellipse.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I looked at a research paper and limit cycles didn't seem to do much with limits of functions.

Comment: My $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ example above is not a "limit of a function." It is looking at the eventual behavior of a sequence $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots\}$ defined by successively iterating a function. I chose discrete time since that is likely easier to grasp than continuous time examples with differential equations (especially if you have never studied differential equations).

Comment: An example continuous time curve that looks like a comet getting trapped by the gravity of the sun is $(x(t),y(t))=(cos(t) + 1/(t^2+1), sin(t)+1/(t^2+2))$ for $t \in [0, 100\pi]$.  The comet spirals around the sun 50 times with a trajectory that approaches the circle "limit cycle," even though it never actually touches the circle.